# Why was Beast suprised by the cure in X-Men 3?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-days-of-future-past, x-men-the-last-stand

In *Days of Future Past* we learn that Beast had created a serum which can temporarily suppress his powers (and treat Xavier...).

Then why is the older Beast in X-Men 3 both surprised and touched when his hand transforms into a human hand during the meeting with Leech?

Additionally, if Beast already knew how to suppress the X-gene in the 60s why didn't he tell anyone? And Professor X knew this as well and could have told someone about it. Especially Rogue, who clearly could have benefited from a temporary "cure".

Additionally, Beast’s serum seems to be better than the "cure" in X-Men 3, since it is not permanent. And it miraculously also cures paraplegia...

Answer (score 8):

Several factors come into play.

Firstly,  *X-Men 3* does not tend to be considered canon:

> According to Lauren Schuler Donner, one of the producers of all of those films, you can now safely consider X-Men 3: The Last Stand and X-Men Origins: Wolverine as non-canon. She explains this at the premier to X-Men: Days of Future Past:
>
> > “Just forget about ‘X3’ and the first ‘Wolverine’ - forget about that, too!“
>
> <sub>From this question: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/106178/3804</sub>

Secondly, the Beast we see in ''Days of Future Past'' had seen the idea of a cure go wrong too often. Firstly with himself,  then Mystique's reaction to the mere *idea*. Finally Bolivar Trask using the same cells, that helped him create his first serum, for the Sentinels. Beast is a smart man. He probably predicted the weaponisation of the cure.

Thirdly he's been campaigning for human-mutant peace since ''X-Men 1''.

[image: Hank McCoy on TV in the bar scene from X-men 1, discussing the mutant debate]

He's likely in awe because:

- He'd given up hope for a 'cure'
- He's aware of the treatment 'Leech' had been given,  but still seemed innocent
- Clearly he still misses being human looking
- He's relieved it's not based on his serum

As for helping Rogue, he probably had too many factors (discussed earlier about Mystique) putting him off.

Professor X is also likely put off because:

- He is for resolving differences, not removing them
- The serum is able to remove his paraplegia; what other side effects might it have?

All this makes Beast's reaction not just plausible, but cromulent.

Comment: I made a guess as to which movie you meant when you said that "Secondly, the Beast we see in had seen". Please correct me if I was wrong.

Comment: Interesting that X-men 3 should not be considered canon. Then why is Wolverine referring to his friendship with Beast when he arrives at the school in the 70s? They become friends in X-men 3.

Comment: @drmanhattan I believe this is because X-Men 3 and the Wolverine movies are considered to be part of a timeline that no longer exists, due to the events of Days of Future Past. Wolverine remembers everything that he experienced in that timeline, but everyone else lived through a new timeline that's still being explained in the films.

Comment: "cromulent". Well played...